# Error when checking the OS on C++ header file

Tags: c++, gcc, header, hashmap, c-preprocessor

I have received some C++ code that I am trying to compile under Linux 64 bits using the provided makefiles.

In that code there is a string_hash.h file containing the code:

```
#ifndef STRING_HASH
#define STRING_HASH

#include <string>
#include "universal_hash_map.h"

#ifdef WINDOWS
typedef stdext::hash_compare<std::string> String_Hasher;
typedef stdext::hash_map< std::string, std::string, stdext::hash_compare<std::string> > String_Hash;
#else
#ifdef LINUX
class String_Hasher: public stdext::hash< std::string > {
private:
    stdext::hash<const char*> hasher;
public:
    String_Hasher() {}
    size_t operator() (const std::string& p) const {
        return hasher(p.c_str());
    }
};
typedef stdext::hash_map< std::string, std::string, String_Hasher > String_Hash;
#endif
#endif

#endif
```

With universal_hash_map.h being:

```
#include "define_os.h"

#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(LINUX)
#include<ext/hash_map>
#define stdext __gnu_cxx;
#else
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include<hash_map>
#endif
#endif
```

and define_os.h:

```
#if defined(WINDOWS) || defined(LINUX)
#else

#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(WIN32)  || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) \
|| defined(WIN64)     || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WIN64__)
#define WINDOWS
#elif defined(sun)       || defined(__sun)      || defined(linux)       || defined(__linux) \
 || defined(__linux__)   || defined(__CYGWIN__) || defined(BSD)         || defined(__FreeBSD__) \
 || defined(__OPENBSD__) || defined(__MACOSX__) || defined(__APPLE__)   || defined(sgi) \
 || defined(__sgi)
#define LINUX
#endif

#endif
```

If I compile the project like that I got the error telling me that the compile can not find stdext::hash

```
Compiling string_functions.o from /home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_functions.cpp.
In file included from /home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_functions.h:5:0,
                 from /home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_functions.cpp:1:
/home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_hash.h:12:29: error: expected class-name before ‘;’ token
/home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_hash.h:12:29: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘;’ token
/home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_hash.h:12:35: error: ‘hash’ in namespace ‘::’ does not name a type
/home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_hash.h:21:9: error: ‘__gnu_cxx’ does not name a type
/home/adria/Code/JensAdria/trunk/thirdparty/pechin/Cpp_Libraries/mylibrary/codes/string_hash.h:21:15: error: ‘hash_map’ in namespace ‘::’ does not name a type
make: *** [string_functions.o] Error 1
```

But what really puzzles me is that if I comment the first line in universal_hash_map.h so it does not include define_os.h, the code compiles fine!

So changing universal_hash_map.h to:

```
//#include "define_os.h"

#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(LINUX)
#include<ext/hash_map>
#define stdext __gnu_cxx;
#else
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include<hash_map>
#endif
#endif
```

or just

```
//#include "define_os.h"

//#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(LINUX)
#include<ext/hash_map>
#define stdext __gnu_cxx;
//#else
//#if defined(_MSC_VER)
//#include<hash_map>
//#endif
//#endif
```

compiles fine.

However in this last example, if I uncomment *#include "define_os.h"* it does not compile :s

So the question is, why trying to define the OS make the code not to compile?

Also, checking gcc predefined symbols it seems that there's nothing wrong there:

```
$ gcc -E -dM - </dev/null | grep linux
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define linux 1
```

EDIT: more info about namespaces

In /usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/hash_map (with no file extension) I have:

```
#ifndef _BACKWARD_HASH_MAP
#define _BACKWARD_HASH_MAP 1

#ifndef _GLIBCXX_PERMIT_BACKWARD_HASH
#include "backward_warning.h"
#endif

#include <bits/c++config.h>
#include <backward/hashtable.h>
#include <bits/concept_check.h>

namespace __gnu_cxx _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

  using std::equal_to;
  using std::allocator;
  using std::pair;
  using std::_Select1st;

  /**
   *  This is an SGI extension.
   *  @ingroup SGIextensions
   *  @doctodo
   */
  template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _HashFn = hash<_Key>,
       class _EqualKey = equal_to<_Key>, class _Alloc = allocator<_Tp> >
    class hash_map
    {
    private:
      typedef hashtable<pair<const _Key, _Tp>,_Key, _HashFn,
            _Select1st<pair<const _Key, _Tp> >,
            _EqualKey, _Alloc> _Ht;

      _Ht _M_ht;

    public:
      typedef typename _Ht::key_type key_type;
```

I don't seem to be able to find the 4.7.3 version of the code that I am running, but [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/api/a01192_source.html) is the 4.7.2 that seems identical to me.

EDIT:
Files after running gcc -E on string_functions.cpp:

[with error (with include)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4028328/withError.txt)

[without Error (without include)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4028328/withoutError.txt)

[diff](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4028328/diff.txt)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a non-standard type, and as such it is not guaranteed to be portable in the way your code has it.

If you can (because your standard library supports it), you should switch to `std::unordered_map`. It is mostly a standard, drop-in replacement for the non-standard `stdext::hash_map` and it will be platform independent without all the `#ifdef`ing.

To test it, you could do something like:

```
#define stdext std
#define hash_map unordered_map
```

If it works, then I'd suggest a quick search and replace of your files.

Another solution, is to go hunt down your hash_map header and find out what namespace it's in. It does not appear to be in __gnu_cxx. It might be in stdext, which may be replaced by the preprocessor to be __gnu_cxx.

Comment: Yes, std::unordered_map seems a much better idea and I considered it, but I would prefer not to touch the code whenever possible. However I still don't understand how defining the OS can affect the compiling result here, specially when it compiles in the last case I posted, but not when I uncomment #include "define_os.h"

Comment: What namespace and header is your hash_map actually in?

Comment: Can you paste a little more (down to where class hash_map is actually declared) or point to a place online that has this file in readable form without downloading a huge zip? Also, you may want to find out what _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION becomes. Could be a constant or another namespace.

Comment: As for why the above won't compile with define_os.h in there, it may be the magic of macros -- your definition of WINDOWS or LINUX may be stomping on something else. You can compare the the output of the preprocessor with and without this include using `gcc -E code.cpp`.

Comment: Can you post a diff of the output of the preprocessor in the working and failing states?

Comment: see last edit (thanks for your help), as I included the files because the diff is over 8,000 lines long.

Comment: Sorry, I've been away. Do you still need help with this?