# Is there an equivalent for stdext::hash_map in gcc

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, dictionary

I am porting some code from Visual Studio to Mingw GCC and I came across this type

```
typedef stdext::hash_map<std::string, SubApplication*> SubApplMap;
```

Now from what I understand is that this is not a standard type. I came across this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014944/error-when-checking-the-os-on-c-header-file) aand [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404085/issue-with-hash-set-hash-set-does-not-name-a-type)  which suggested replacing it with unordered_map  by doing the following

```
#include <unordered_map>
#define stdext std
#define hash_map unordered_map
```

as a result I get the following error

```
 error: 'hash_multimap' is not a member of 'std'
 #define stdext std
                 ^
```

Any suggestions on what I could replace this container by ?

Comment: Those `#define`s are a bad idea, you should just do the work and replace `stdext::hash_map` with `std::unordered_map`. Hopefully the interfaces are similar enough that it won't be ton of work. As for the error, my guess is your code makes use of `stdext::hash_multimap` elsewhere and the `#define stdext std` is messing with that. Replace that type with `std::unordered_multimap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
typedef stdext::hash_map<std::string, SubApplication*> SubApplMap;
```

I would just get rid of the `hash_map` all together

```
using SubApplMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, SubApplication*>;
```

Instead of trying to play games with preprocessor macros.

Note that this requires C++11.

Comment: Yes I have enabled C++11. Also My typedef was inside my class . Should I comment the typedef and place the above statement instead of it (inside the class)?

Comment: Yes you should. In fact, don't just comment it out, delete the line :)

Comment: I am getting the following error `error: expected ';' before 'SubApplMap'
     using SubApplMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, SubApplication*> SubApplMap;` any suggestions ?

Comment: You have an extra `SubApplMap` at the end of the statement right before the semi-colon, get rid of it.